# creating image in header using XSL template

Tags: xslt

I want to insert a image in header. please let me know know to insert that image? my template look like this
 please let me know how to do this
 my image name is ABC.jpg

```
<xsl:template name="insertGlossaryEvenFooter">
<fo:static-content flow-name="even-glossary-footer">          
<fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="__glossary__even__footer">  
<xsl:call-template name="insert Variable">                  
<xsl:with-param name="theVariableID" select="'Glossary even footer'"/>                     <xsl:with-param name="the Parameters">          
<pagenum>                           
<fo:inline xsl:use-attribute-sets="__glossary__even__footer__pagenum">                                 <fo:page-number/>   
</fo:inline>                         
</pagenum>                     
</xsl:with-param>                 
</xsl:call-template>             
</fo:block>         
</fo:static-content>      </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the static-content block, you can add a block that contains the image:

```
<fo:block-container position... top... left... width.. height> 
    <fo:external-graphic src="ABC.jpg">
</fo:block-container>
```

You'll have to add another block-container in which you'll place the footer text.